# Can't access world methods in AfterFeatures hook

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

I have an AfterFeatures hook that I'm using to try to gracefully shut down an expressjs web server that is used for testing only. In this hook, I need to call the visit method, which has been added to World, but I apparently don't have access to World from within this hook. What can I do to gain access to things in World inside this and other hooks?

```js
// features/support/after_hooks.js
var myAfterHooks = function () {
  this.registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function (event, callback) {
    this.visit('/quit', callback);
  });
};
module.exports = myAfterHooks;
```

Comment: You get the same behaviour in `BeforeFeatures`, it is most odd that you would expect things like servers to be kicked off in the `BeforeFeatures` and cleaned up in the `AfterFeatures`, however currently there is no access to the world like you say, it has been raised as a bug on their issue board for a while and is in one of the milestones, but I am not sure when it will get done. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can. In the AfterFeatures the cucumber process has already finished, so **this** no longer references it.

But, if all you want is to visit a page, you can register your browser outside cucumber so that it is still accessible from the AfterFeatures hook. If you are using AngularJS + Protractor, Protractor handles the browser for you, and therefore it is still accessible in the AfterFeatures hook. It would be the same principle. This can be done with the following.

hooks.js

```
var myHooks = function () {


    this.registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function (event, callback) {
      console.log('----- AfterFeatures hook');
      // This will not work as the World is no longer valid after the features
      // outside cucumber
      //this.visit('/quit', callback);  

      // But the browser is now handled by Protractor so you can do this
      browser.get('/quit').then(callback);
    });

};

module.exports = myHooks;
```

world.js

```
module.exports = function() {

  this.World = function World(callback) {

    this.visit = function(url) {
        console.log('visit ' + url);
        return browser.get(url);
    };

    callback();
  };
}
```

The AfterFeatures example in the cucumber-js GitHub repository is a little misleading, as it looks like you can access the driver that you previously registered in the World. But if you are using pure cucumber-js only, I have not seen that work.

By the way, you can use just this instead of registerHandler.

```
this.AfterFeatures(function (event, callback) {
     browser.get('/quit').then(callback);
});
```

Hope this helps.